# Different colours for daughters and daughter-in-laws in Gramps Relationship graph

Tags: family-tree, gramps

I have just very recently begun with genealogy and just started using Gramps.

I have collected a lot of information about the family and want to show it through a relationship graph. In that, I would like to show separate colours for daughters and different for daughter-in-laws in the family. Gramps graphs have an option to give different colour for males and females, but I couldn't find any such option as I needed.